FormIO icons showing exclamation mark with font-awesome-pro in react project
I was trying to implement FormIO in my project, previously I was using font-awesome-free and it was working fine. As soon I have upgraded to font-awesome-pro, icons in form builder showing as big question mark in circular and not loading any icons.
How can I fix this issue? Can I use pro and free version together.
I try to install the font-awesome-free as well and imported in the tsx file where FormIO is used
Package.json
"@formio/react": "^5.2.4-rc.1",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^6.6.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.6.0",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.2",

Here's what I see:


Are you sure you're actually importing both libraries?
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons';
import { far } from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons';

library.add(fas, far);

Moreover, it's unlikely for FormIO not to need extra configuration because I think it's looking for free icons by default. So you may check the console logs for possible errors. Share them.

Thanks for help. Most of the icons are loaded now.
But, images are still not loading - Radio, Time, Content, Tabs
